# Create-React-App not reading environment variable from docker-compose.yml

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: user1/webapp:latest
    volumes:
      - ./local-db:/go/src/webapp/local-db
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_ENDPOINT=http://api.com
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

`webapp` is server that serves a create-react-app but when I run

```
console.log("process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT")
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT)
```

according to https://daveceddia.com/multiple-environments-with-react/
I should be able to access the environment variables. I run the docker-compose using

```
docker swarm init 
docker stack deploy -c ~/webapp/docker-compose.yml webapp
```

The console log prints `undefined` but if I run the server serving create-react-app on my local machine without docker, the frontend properly prints the environment variable.

Answer (score 7):

I noticed a lot of people struggle with this, and particularly how to pass ENV vars instead of conditional scripting in Dockerfile, so I provided a simplified Github repo tutorial:

- https://github.com/mikesparr/tutorial-react-docker

Background via a public article on LinkedIn articles if you care to read:

- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dockerizing-your-react-app-mike-sparr/

---

In short, you need your Dockerfile `CMD` to run a script that performs the `build` and the `server start` steps so the app can use the runtime container configs.

Also, you need to prefix your ENV vars with `REACT_APP_<yourvarname>` and in your app, reference them using `process.env.REACT_APP_SOMEVAR`.

Comment: _Bootstrapped React apps (using create-react-app) strip most environment variables with the exception of NODE_ENV and any variables that are prefixed with REACT_APP_<your var>._  Yowza.  I didn't realize this. Changed variable names = success. Many thx.

Comment: It works only if you use "npm run" command, but if you have a Dockerfile which does the npm run build command, the .env variables are left out.

Answer (score 5):

Create-react-app prefers to have a .env file in order to embed your env vars into the build.

Obviously it's not a good practice to version control a .env file, the create-react-app official documentation go *against* the 12-factor-app philosophy.

So let's use a **clean** solution ! The most simple way is to create a .env file on the fly into the Dockerfile build environment :

For this create a simple script `create-env-file.sh` :

```
touch .env

for envvar in "$@" 
do
   echo "$envvar" >> .env
done
```

It will copy every args you pass it to a new .env file

Then call it before `RUN npm run build` in your Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY src/ ./src/
COPY public/ ./public/
COPY pack*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY create-env-file.sh ./create-env-file.sh

RUN npm i

# Add as many arguments as you want to pass environment variables 
#   and use an ARG command for each one, so Dockerfile context will grab it from --build-arg

ARG REACT_APP_ENDPOINT

RUN sh create-env-file.sh REACT_APP_ENDPOINT=$REACT_APP_ENDPOINT

# If you want to debug the .env file, uncomment the following line
# CMD ["cat", ".env"]

RUN npm run build

RUN npm i -g serve

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["serve", "-s", "build"]
```

Then use `--build-arg` to pass your env vars to the docker build command :

```
docker build --build-arg REACT_APP_ENDPOINT=http://api.com -t front-server .
```

You have to reference each passed build arg with an ARG command because docker build consider build args as arguments and NOT environment variables. [See here](https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-pass-environment-variables/#intermission-arg-vs-env)

So your docker-compose.yml would look like this :

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        REACT_APP_ENDPOINT=http://api.com
    image: user1/webapp:latest
    volumes:
      - ./local-db:/go/src/webapp/local-db
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Use `--build` with docker-compose up :

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks!!!

Comment: Using this approach, is it possible to build the image and then set the args in docker-compose later?

Comment: When you use the build to set the arguments you need to create a docker image per environment. You rather want a single image that can be used by multiple environments.

Answer (score 1):

Create React App has support for .env files, which means you can put permanent environment variables in one of these files to make it available to the app.

You are putting yours in your `docker-compose.yml`.

There is a solution for handling this found here:
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/982#issuecomment-273032553.

Specifically, step #3.

Comment: From what I can see, this answer does not specifically answer the original question, how to read an environmental variable for a create-react-app docker container.  Instead it shows how to build a single container from a known directory on a single computer.  Hint, when we deploy a system, there are often multiple containers in a single location (frontend, backend, db, management tools, etc....)  For anyone with multiple containers, this answer is nice, but doesn't help.  And when we do multiple containers, we build from a git repo.  .env files won't work.